# Concept on sequence-series.

Tags: sequences-and-series

As we know if want to see the convergence of a series we can see it by seeing the corresponding sequence of its partial sum.
Now I want know if the vice -versa is correct or not.
Plzz.  Clear my doudt.

Comment: This is the definition of a series. A series converges by definition if and only if the sequence of its partial sums converges.

Comment: So, can't be vice -versa true ??

Comment: It's by definition true. Saying "the series converges" is just another way of saying "the sequence of partial sums converges". So it is the the case that: "the series converges" $\Longleftrightarrow$ "the sequence of partial sums converges" (by definition).

Comment: Yes, *if and only if"... as @anakhronizein has said... so the "vice versa" is true too. So you can derive convergence of the sequence of partial sums from the convergence of the series. (This is not used very often, but is nevertheless valid.)

Comment: Thanks @anakhronizein.